# Execute an if statement inside a for loop only once

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I want to check every entry inside a table with an if statement and a for loop and do sth only once if it's true. e.g.:

```
int[][] table = new int[5][5]
int number = 4;

for(int i=0;i<table.length;i++)
   { 
     if(table[i][0] != number)
     {
       do something;
     }
   }
```

So it checks for the first column if an entry equals number and if it does not it executes the "do something". But I only want to execute "do something" when the entire column does not equal number only once and not for each entry.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using a counter that always increases when

```
if(table[i][0] != number)
```

is true and if the counter equals 0 I execute the "do something".

Answer (score 0):

you can simply break a loop.

```
loop_name: for(int i=0;i<table.length;i++) { 
     if(table[i][0] != number)
     {
       do something;
       break loop_name;
     }
   }
```

and after first time that condition become true, 'do something' and break the loop;

Comment: The "break loop_name;" is quite advanced, i.e. very rare in most code. To exit the current loop, a simple "break;" suffices.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    int[][] table = new int[5][5]
    int number = 4;
    // use this flag to signal the condition violation
    boolean flag = false;
    
    for(int i=0;i<table.length;i++)
       { 
         if(table[i][0] == number)
         {
           flag == true;
           break;
         }
       }
     if(!flag) doSomething();
```

Comment: The flag is quite a good solution for a lot such problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try

```
do {do_stuff; table[i][0] = number;} while (table[i][0] != number);
```